# Slow Page Rank algorithm on Neo4j desktop

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I am running Neo4j on a 32 GB workstation. I am running page rank algorithm for it as described here: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/page-rank/. I downloaded and installed neo4j desktop. For a .3 GB graph Neo4j seems to be taking a lot of time. I followed the steps as described here: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/page-rank/. Since my machine is 32 GB with SSD. Can I change some system parameters in Neo4j to speed up the algorithm

Comment: What're current neo4j configurations like heap size, page cache?

Comment: @Raj Good question. How do I find those? I googled but the answers do not work for me

Comment: It's defined in neo4j.conf file under conf directory of Neo4j. You are using Neo4j desktop then you can check this in the settings tab.   File locations depend on the installation, you can check it for your installation here https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/